I'm trying to validate a TextInput field on my whatsapp flow but i'm failing. How can I do it?
{
   "type": "TextInput",
   "required": true,
   "label": "National ID  Number",
   "name": "national_id",
   "input-type": "text",
   "min-chars": 14,
   "max-chars":15,
   "helper-text": "eg. 70-123456-C-78"
                                
}

On my personal details screen, I'm taking user ID from the textInput, however, I want to validate the input I get using this pattern "^(?i)\d{2}-\d{5,7}-[A-Za-z]-\d{2}$". How can I do it?
I tried using pattern but im getting the error "property pattern is not allowed"

Flows don't support regular expression for validation at this point. You can only validate this by adding an endpoint which would submit the value to your backend server to validate the field and return an error message to the flow. You can display an error message using the field "error-message" on the TextInput
Documentation for adding Flow endpoint https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows/guides/implementingyourflowendpoint
